# React render component containing only function

Tags: reactjs

I'm very very new to react (still learning). One thing I noticed is that `component` always have a return with HTML (`jsx`) as content.

But I was wondering if it's possible to create a `component` containing only functions. For example, in my `footer` I only have static content. Just plain text and a `button` to go to the homepage. So this is what I'm trying to do:

*index.html*

```
<body>
    <main id="app"></main>

    <footer id="footer">
        <!-- Some other content -->
        <button onClick={this.onButton}>Home</button>
    </footer>

    <script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

*Footer.js*

```
class Footer extends React.Component {
    onButton() {
        console.log('Button clicked');
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render');
        return null;
    }
}

render(<Footer/>, window.document.getElementById("footer"));
```

This way, the `component` gets executed and I can see the log, however, the `button` defined in the `index.html` is removed.

On the other hand, if I remove the `render()` from the `component`, I get this error:

> Footer(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`.

---

One thing I forgot to mention before, and also based on the item 2 of @aks answer, about using plaing html to create the links is that it's going to reload the whole page if I don't use the React router I'm currently using.

So, for example, If I create a link on the fotter with plain html like this:

```
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

When clicking on the link everything else is going to reset, because the page is going to refresh.

This is why it would be better to just use a function from a component instead of using the whole html declared inside the component.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. I will answer your question in points:

1. Render method is a required method, you cannot do without it, it can return `null`, as you are already doing.
2. If you say that your footer is static markup and links to some part, You don't even need the `js` file. It is not required.
3. In case you have components for most other parts, the static content may look too verbose. You can put those content in the render method of the `Footer` component as make the `index.html` very clean. Then in case you need more features in future, you can add them safely.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Well, yes, I agree. Maybe the example I gave was also way too simple. Still in the same contest, imagine I would have an input and button to fill my e-mail and subscribe to a newsletter, but all the rest would be plain text. Would you still turn it into a component? Or another given context where it would be "too much" to create a component to use just a function.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade I think this will be opinionated. I will try to keep it consistent the way I am doing things in other places of my codebase. If I personally had to make choices, I would still create a `Footer` component, as from the view hierarchy the `SubscribePane` is inside the footer. I will keep all of these inside the component, and if the complexity demand even break down the subscription things into a component in future.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade I also forgot to add about Single source of truth, so if tomorrow you want some changes and a new developer is working on it, where should he look for the markup? In jsx or html?

Comment: In this case, in the HTML file.

Comment: I edited my question. I noticed one thing when using a link declared using only `html`. It works, but also refresh the page, losing the "SPA" feeling when using the React router.